# Its shows error in import pdfkit in python

Tags: python, python3, pip, wkhtmltopdf

I am Using python3 for coding in Ubuntu...
I have already installed pip

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Version

```
pip3 --version
```

Output

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

Install wkhtmltopdf:

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

wkhtmltopdf version output

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4
```

Installing pdfkit

```
 pip install pdfkit
```

when i use pdfkit sample in pycharm

```
    import pdfkit

pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_file('test.html', 'out.pdf')
pdfkit.from_string('Hello!', 'out.pdf')
```

is shows

```
/home/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/bin/python "/home/user/PycharmProjects/sample project/venv/pipSample.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/sample project/venv/pipSample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pdfkit
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pdfkit'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want a reply guys please...

Comment: `pip3 install pdfkit` : pip is python2 ..... and pip3 is python3 !

Comment: I just installed it...then once i try again.. Import pdfkit. It shows no module pdfkit ..

Comment: Did you do $ **pip3** install pdfkit ? ?

Comment: @KnudLarsen Same..No module pdfkit named pdfkit

Comment: man..my problems are solved when I changed the python version from 3.6 to 3.8